# 404 Not Found: Angular 2 can't talk to Spring Rest API

Tags: spring, rest, angular

I followed Angular 2's Tour of Hero tutorial with in memory database. Then I created a Spring backend to supply data and want to integrate Angular2 with Spring's Rest API.

In Tour of Hero I only changed one line of code in hero.service.ts:

```
/* private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes'; */
private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/hero/all';
```

The link I changed to is the the Spring service endpoint, if I type the link in browser, it returns JSON data: `[{"id":1,"name":"test"}]`.

However, I am getting error in Tour of Hero:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null
```

It looks like the spring endpoint of `localhost:8080` is not found by Angular application running on `localhost:3000`. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have a look at network tab and see what's the actual url that it hits

Comment: Hi. Did you ever get to resolve this issue? I experience similar issues, with running Angular 2 and Spring both on the same port or separately. What I get is 404 `'Not Found for URL: <url>'` error. In my case I am not even sure it gets to the server side, because it gives the same error regardless if the server is up or down.

Answer (score 3):

This was asked a while ago, but probably someone finds it useful.

Delete the following dependency from your package.json:

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
```

Remove it from `node_modules` directory, delete all `InMemoryWebApiModule` and `InMemoryWebApiModule` and `InMemoryDataService`-related code.