# Angular 4 HttpClient Get Request 404 Not Found Error

Tags: angular, rest, get, httpclient

[image]I am getting an error when running my Angular 4 application written with Typescript, HTML, and CSS.

The error reads: GET http://localhost:4200/typeahead-component (404) NOT FOUND

This is my related code:

```
  public url: string = "typeahead-component/";

  return this.http
      .get(this.url)
      .subscribe(
          response => {
              console.log(response);
          },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                  console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
              } else {
                  console.log("entering http get request.");
                  console.log(this.url);
                  console.log(err);
              }
          }
```

I am connecting my Angular 4 front-end to Spring Boot REST API back-end code. This is the relevant code in the back-end:

```
@GetMapping("typeahead-component/")
public List<String> get() {
    System.out.println("Entering getApps call.");
    return getApps.get();
}
```

I am trying to get a list of applications from the server via the server webpage's HTML.

I have seen this similar Stack Overflow post [Angular 2 HTTP GET 404 Not Found for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923209/angular-2-http-get-404-not-found-for-url) but my issue is not related to in-memory-web-api.

I have also seen this post [Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser) but was not able to solve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: so you are getting an `html` file from a path correct?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, correct.

Comment: is your service is running in the port `4200`??

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: in which port your service is running? also the file name is missing `.html` extension

Comment: It is running on http://localhost:4200 . I will look into the file name. I'm not sure where to add the .html extension.

Comment: Probably your spring application should be running on a different port. whereas your angular app is running on 4200. you can't just pass your spring path mapping into angular app. Since there is no router mapping is set in the routing module, it will throw 404 . could you tell me on which port your spring application is running?

Comment: How do I check which port my Spring application is running on?

Comment: when you run your spring application it will run on a specific port like localhost:xxxx/

Comment: you already told that you are running two app (front end and backend) the front end is running on 4200 but i need to know on which port you are running the back end (spring app)

Comment: I am not sure which port the back-end is running on. I am also not sure how I can check which port the back-end is running on - how I can find that specific port.

Comment: Is your service execute on your same port?